# Difference between using instance variables vs 'attr_reader'

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, accessor

What is the difference between using `@name` and `name` (with an `attr_reader`)? They use different path ways: `@name` is direct while `name` uses a method to reach `@name`. But besides that, is there any difference? The outcome is the same.

Answer (score 2):

> But besides that is there any difference because the outcome is the same.

Besides that? Not much. It's just that `attr_reader` gives you a method (as you already know), so you can do all the things you do to methods: make public/private, decorate, override in a child class, include from a module, etc.

Oh, and also instance variables are harder to access from outside the class. Which is why `attr_reader` and related helpers exist in the first place (to easily wrap ivars in public methods).